# Removing duplicate users from a list using set()

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

Trying to remove duplicate users from list with set in python. The problem is that it is not removing the duplicate users:

```
with open ('live.txt') as file: 
        for line in file.readlines(): 
                word = line.split()
                users = (word[word.index('user')+1]) 
                        l  = users.split() 
                        l = set(l)
                        l = sorted(l)
                        print " ".join(l)
```

Here's the contents of `live.txt`:

```
Sep 15 04:34:24 li146-252 sshd[13320]: Failed password for invalid user ronda from 212.58.111.170 port 42201 ssh2
Sep 15 04:34:26 li146-252 sshd[13322]: Failed password for invalid user ronda from 212.58.111.170 port 42330 ssh2
Sep 15 04:34:28 li146-252 sshd[13324]: Failed password for invalid user ronda from 212.58.111.170 port 42454 ssh2
Sep 15 04:34:31 li146-252 sshd[13326]: Failed password for invalid user ronda from 212.58.111.170 port 42579 ssh2
Sep 15 04:34:33 li146-252 sshd[13328]: Failed password for invalid user romero from 212.58.111.170 port 42715 ssh2
Sep 15 04:34:36 li146-252 sshd[13330]: Failed password for invalid user romero from 212.58.111.170 port 42838 ssh2
```

Comment: this should a one time activity.There should not be a need for a loop

Comment: Please add a sample value for `users`!

Comment: Do you mind adding your users here. And what output is expected

Comment: Updated with the whole code. @Optimus

Comment: Is it like that you want to get all unique users from the live.txt ? so from above screen you want [ronda, romero]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you want:

```
with open ('live.txt') as file: 
    users = []
    for line in file.readlines(): 
        word = line.split()
        users.append(word[word.index('user') + 1])
    unique_users = list(set(users))
print " ".join(unique_users)
```

Output:

```
romero ronda
```

Comment: How would it be if you want to use dictionary to count how many times a user appears?

Comment: @user3270211: Please, do not use `for line in file.readlines()`, use `for line in file` instead. btw, `word` is missleading -- it should be `words` instead. And you do not need to call `list()` here.

Comment: @user3270211 Just do control if user is in dict. If they are not in dict, add value 1 to dict[user]. If they are already in dict, change the value to dict[user] + 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a much simpler way as

```
list(set(<Your user list>))
```

This will return list with no duplicate. Python has datatype `set` which is collection of unique element. So just by typecasting your `list` to `set` will automatically remove the duplicates

Example:

```
>>> users = ['john', 'mike', 'ross', 'john','obama','mike']
>>> list(set(users))
['mike', 'john', 'obama', 'ross']
>>>
```

I hope this will solve your problem:

```
import re
def remove_me():
    all_users = []
    with open ('live.txt') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            pattern = re.compile('(.*user\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)')
            stmt = pattern.match(line)
            all_users.append(stmt.groups()[1])
    unique_users = list(set(all_users))
    print unique_users

if __name__ == "__main__":
    remove_me()
```

Comment: This is what I get in return:['a', 'e', 'k', 'm', '3', 'p', 's', 't']
['a', 'e', 'k', 'm', '3', 'p', 's', 't']
['a', 'e', 'k', 'm', '3', 'p', 's', 't']
['a', 'e', 'k', 'm', '3', 'p', 's', 't']
['a', 'e', 'k', 'm', '3', 'p', 's', 't']

Comment: I forgot to mention that every user is in a own list.

Answer (score 0):

If duplicate user lines are consecutive; you could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to remove duplicates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def extract_user(line):
    return line.partition('user')[2].partition('from')[0].strip()

with open('live.txt') as file:
    print(" ".join(map(itemgetter(0), groupby(file, key=extract_user))))
    # -> ronda romero
```